# Using sed to modify Informatica parameter file

Tags: sed, informatica

I have an entry in my `Informatica` parameter file, it looks like this:

```
$FileName=inputfile20140801.csv
```

I would like to use `sed` to update the value `inputfile20140801` to `inputfile20140802`

Earlier in the code I captured the value `inputfile20140802` in a variable `$fileName`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sed to replace string in file with contents of variable of that name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581495/using-sed-to-replace-string-in-file-with-contents-of-variable-of-that-name)

Comment: This is an Informatica question. Post a more general one asking about editing text files with Bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `s` (substitute) command like this:

```
sed -i 's/$FileName=.*\.csv/$FileName='"$fileName"'.csv/' input.file
```

Note that I've separated the variable `$fileName` in double quotes. This is because variables will not get expanded in a single quoted string in bash, but single quotes are the best choice for a sed program since it contains possibly many characters which would need to get escaped if we would use double quotes.

Btw, you'll need to [learn about the sed commands](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) if you want to use it.